# Json element value returning null though found in request body

Tags: json, playframework, playframework-2.4

I am trying to pass some json data

```
{  
   "name":"srk",
   "age":25,
   "interests":"programming"
}
```

through ajax and fetching the request body into play controller as shown below.

```
@BodyParser.Of(BodyParser.Json.class)
    public Result example(){
      JsonNode jsonNode = request().body().asJson();
      Logger.info("requestBody = "+ jsonNode);
    }
```

The above logger prints the request payload sent during the request exactly
like below:

```
{"name": "srk", "age":25, "interests" : "programming"}
```

But when I try to print age they it is showing up as null.

```
String age = jsonNode.findPath("age").textValue();
Logger.info("age= "+ age);
```

This is printing `age= null`

Any ideas would help.

Comment: One guess is that, since age is a number, not a string, that textValue returns null instead of converting the number to a string, as one would expect.  You could try converting the returned object to a String with toString(), e.g. `jsonNode.findPath("age").toString();`

Comment: @DBug: Correct, it is working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I cannot yet comment, I'm writing a proper answer in the name of @DBug.
@srk, please choose a correct answer and mark the question as solved =)

The JSonNode `.textValue()` method seems not to automatically convert between content types. Since `age` is a numeric field, the `textValue()` is actually null. There are two possible solutions:

You can retrieve the node content as the correct type with:

```
jsonNode.findPath("age").asInt();
```

You can retrieve the node content as a String with either:

```
jsonNode.findPath("age").asText();
//or
jsonNode.findPath("age").toString();
```

I went looking for the documentation here: [com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonNode.html)

Direct link to [textValue()](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonNode.html#textValue()) description.

Direct link to [asInt()](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonNode.html#asInt()) description.

Direct link to [asText()](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonNode.html#asText()) description.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `jsonNode.get("age").asInt()` to get the value instead of `findPath`